# How to extract the destination place of an Icmp inst or a binaryOperator Inst in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Now I want to get the destination place of an Icmp Inst, for example, if I got an Icmp Inst such as:

```
%cmp = icmp sgt i32 %0, 1
```

how can I get the destination place '%cmp' ?
And for BinaryOperator Inst such as :

```
%dec = add nsw i32 %2, -1
```

how can I get the '%dec' ?

I have tried using 
`Value* des = icmp->getOperand(0);`,but it seems wrong.And I tried searching in Google ,but didn't get the satisfying answer, does anyone can tell me how to solve the problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then the `icmp` itself is the destination value you are looking for. I.e.,

Change

```
Value* des = icmp->getOperand(0);
```

to

```
Value* des = icmp;
```